# Displaying Xquery (.xq) Files in a Browser

Tags: xquery

I am new to programming and very new to xml / xquery

I have a .xq file (with html and xquery code) and .xml file (to store data).

While testing it, I can view how the .xq page would display using stylus studio, but I can't get the page to function using a webserver or webhost. I know this isnt unusual, but I havent been able to work out how to fix it (or if it is even possible).

In the meantime I've been using Saxon which works well, but not ideal having to use a command line code completely separate to the application.

I've also read that Jedit is an option but I couldnt get the xquery/saxon plugins to work with xquery. I also wondered if it is possible to use a stylesheet but couldnt find anything on this.

So first question, is it possible for a browser (ie using a webhost) to display a .xq file?
And also any recommendations for other software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to access and execute your XQuery programs through a web browser, then you will need an XQuery engine with a web server.  There are a number of such products.  I personally use and can recommend [eXist-db](http://exist-db.org/), a free, open source native XML database.  In addition to efficiently storing, indexing, and querying your XML, eXist-db runs by default with a lightweight web server, allowing you to access your queries through your browser at, for example, http://localhost:8080/exist/apps/myapp/myquery.xq.  Accessing this URL would cause eXist-db to look for your query (myquery.xq) in the database's "myapp" directory, and assuming it is indeed there, eXist-db would execute the query and serialize the results to the browser.  It's quite a powerful combination - XQuery and a native XML database + web server like eXist-db.  Feel free to read more about eXist-db's [documentation](http://exist-db.org/exist/documentation.xml), and ask questions about eXist-db at the [exist-open mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/exist-open).  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Like Joe says, you need a web application framework that is capable of executing XQuery code. Most obvious choice is an XML database of any kind that comes with a web server. eXist-db is one example. MarkLogic ( [www.marklogic.com](http://www.marklogic.com) ) is another. There also is Sausalito ( [www.28msec.com](http://www.28msec.com) ), which comes with an Eclipse-derived developer environment that allows local testing in a small web server. You could also look into ServletX ( [www.expath.org](http://www.expath.org) ), a small web container for executing xslt, xproc, xquery, and such. With a little more effort you could even take something like Cocoon, put Saxon ( [www.saxonica.com](http://www.saxonica.com) ) behind it, and use that to execute your XQuery. All mentioned examples allow running code for free, even the products from commercial vendors..

HTH!